# Save output python in string variable

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables, output

I want to save my output in a string variable.
My main goal was to check if different IP addresses are up or down. However, there is a problem for one address IP. Indeed, the IP Address is down but the code say it's up.
i ping with a cmd and that's show me : Unable to reach the destination host
and say 0% loss.

So, i want to detect if there is the world Unable to make an additional condition.

I tried different library but never worked.

```
hostname = "192.168.1.2"
somevar = str(os.system("ping " + hostname))
print(somevar)
```

The output is 0.
And i want the output to be : 
send a ping request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `os.system` will not give you the desired output. It returns just the exit code of the ping command (or any other command).

If you want to get the text output that would be seen on the console try the *subprocess* module.

```
import subprocess
import sys

hostname = "192.168.1.2"
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["ping", hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# run command and save output and error msg
stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()

# stderr is None -> everything is fine
if stderr == None:
    print(stdout)
else:
    print(stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

This surely isn't exactly what you want, but it might give you an idea of how you could solve your problem.